# Deploy single service in a monorepo Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-fabric

I'm working with azure devops, my project is a monorepo contain multiple services host in github.
Every time I make change(s) in one service, I have to build all the others (loop through all folders and build) then push it to fabric.
How can I config azure to build and push only changed project?
Here is my solution folder structure

```
Microservices/  
    ├── Service A/
    ├── Service B/
    └── Service C/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box solution. A workaround is setting up multiple pipelines for Services and triggered by changes in each Service folder. For example:

```
Microservices/ 
    ├── azure-pipelines.yml 
    ├── Service A/
        |── azure-pipelines-a.yml
    ├── Service B/
        |── azure-pipelines-b.yml
    └── Service C/
        |── azure-pipelines-c.yml
```

And use the path filter to decide which yaml will be triggered. For example:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - ServiceA/*
```

In addition, you can use [Step templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#step-templates) for the steps used in multiple builds.

Comment: Thanks for your solution  

I did some research and found that I can get latest change(s) from git through powershell

but this is for Azure Repo Git.

How can I achieve this with github? My idea is get latest commit and check the path and build only changed project

Comment: Here is powershell step 
steps: 
  - powershell: |
      $url="$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)/changes?api-version=5.1"
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method GET
                       
      $changesFolder = $result.changes | Where-Object{$_.item.gitObjectType -match "tree"} | Select-Object -Property {$_.item.path}

Comment: The powershell script used Azure DevOps REST api, in GitHub, you could fetch the commit via the Get a Commit API, the response will include a `files` array with the list of changed files: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-commit. By the way, there is a public blog did some Powershell scripting to achieve the mono repo single build solution, which may give you another solution. You may have a look at it: https://dev.to/nikolicbojan/azure-devops-yaml-build-for-mono-repository-with-multiple-projects-146g.